VBA - Returning just upper case characters in a string
I am building a dynamic macro in Excel's VBA using our usernames using Environ("Username") and need to extract the upper case characters. So JohnSmith becomes JS
I can't get the macro to return just the initials. It just gives me a blank reply
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Dim Username As String
Dim UserInits As String
Username = Environ("UserName")
Dim i As Integer
Dim spltStr() As String
spltStr = Split(Username)

UserInits = ""

i = 1
Do While i <= Len(Username)

    If UCase(spltStr(i)) = spltStr(i) Then
        UserInits = UserInits & spltStr(i)
    End If
    
i = i + 1
Loop

MsgBox UserInits

End Sub

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Couple of bits I can see. Split(Username) - This splits by a delimiter character, if the delimiter is omitted it uses a space, so spltStr is likely to be an array with 1 element if your user names don't have spaces.  You then set i=1 but arrays start at 0 so with my username which doesn't have spaces I got an error as it was looking for spltStr(1) but mine only has splStr(0).

I doubt that your code runs at all. Reason is that the command Split(Username) is not doing what you expect. Split splits a string into words, using a delimiter character. If you omit the 2nd parameter (the delimiter), space is used. So split("JohnSmith") will return only one element (with index 0), Split(John Smith) will return two elements, `Split("A;B;C", ";") will return 3.
Following your code, spltStr(i) should throw an runtime error 9 Subscript out of Range as your Split command surely doesn't create an array with as many elements as characters in the name (plus it's index is always 0-based).
If you want to check for a single character, just use the mid-function with a third parameter = 1.
The following trivial function will extract the uppercase characters from a string.
Function GetInitials(s As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        Dim c As String
        c = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If UCase(c) = c And Asc(c) > 32 Then
            GetInitials = GetInitials & c
        End If
    Next i
End Function

And the call could look like this:
Sub t1()
    Dim Username As String
    Username = Environ("UserName")
    
    MsgBox GetInitials(Username)
    ' or
    MsgBox GetInitials("User FunThomas gave me a good Answer on StackOverflow")
    
End Sub



Fantastic. Worked perfectly. Thanks

A similar answer to @FunThomas.  This also removes hyphens.
Public Sub Test()

    MsgBox UserInitials(Environ("UserName"))
    MsgBox GetInitials("Timorgano")

End Sub

Public Function UserInitials(UserName As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Ans As String
    Dim ThisChar As String
    For i = 1 To Len(UserName)
        ThisChar = Mid(UserName, i, 1)
        If ThisChar = UCase(ThisChar) Then
            'Check it's a letter and not another character like a hyphen.
            If Asc(ThisChar) >= 65 And Asc(ThisChar) <= 90 Then
                Ans = Ans & ThisChar
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    UserInitials = Ans
End Function  

Formula version:
=LET(UserName,$A$1,
     Letters,MID(UserName,SEQUENCE(LEN(UserName)),1),
     Capitals,BYROW(Letters,LAMBDA(ThisChar,IF(AND(CODE(ThisChar)>=65,CODE(ThisChar)<=90),ThisChar,""))),
     TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,Capitals))

Edit:  Have updated to take into account accented characters and any other characters - just add it to the Letters string.
Public Sub Test()

    MsgBox UserInitials("Mr. Arnold Österreicher") & vbCr & _
           UserInitials("Ms. Ännchen Schmidt") & vbCr & _
           UserInitials(Environ("UserName"))

End Sub

Public Function UserInitials(UserName As String) As String
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Ans As String
    Dim ThisChar As String
    
    Dim Letters As String
    Letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ"
    
    For i = 1 To Len(UserName)
        ThisChar = Mid(UserName, i, 1)
        If InStr(Letters, ThisChar) > 0 Then
            Ans = Ans & ThisChar
        End If
    Next i
    UserInitials = Ans
    
End Function


This unfortunately will fail for Mr. Arnold Österreicher and Ms. Ännchen Schmidt

@FunThomas fair point.

I like your 2nd attempt, but I like the attempt to use Ucase better. Just did a check: UCase handles nearly 1000 characters (checked with ChrW), so maybe the reverse attempt would be better, using an exclusion list of characters (like hyphen or apostrophe)

RegExp is an option.
Function GetInitials(strTxt As String) As String
    With CreateObject("vbScript.Regexp")
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "[^A-Z]"
        GetInitials = .Replace(strTxt, "")
    End With
End Function

Sub Test()
    MsgBox GetInitials("John Smith is a hero.")
End Sub

